# Drools DSL parser logging

Tags: logging, drools, dsl

Drools DSL parser fails with error related to drl syntax which has scarce information about DSL itself. It may be hard to guess which parts of DSL where parsed successfully and which exact peace is not parsable.

Is there a way to print which peace of DSL was not parsed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drools has debug [option](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_bpm_suite/6.2/html/development_guide/sect-domain_specific_languages_dsls#Debug_Options_for_DSL_Expansion) to enable logging of the result of the parsing.

```
#/result
```

With additional logging configuration

```
org.drools.compiler.lang.dsl.DefaultExpander=debug
```

It will print expanded DSL where you can easily find non-parsable snippet.